# Wifi Api in WINDOW PHONE 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, api, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, wifi

I just wanna know does Window Phone 7 has WIFI API for accessing it, how can i access window phone 7 wifi to perform some actions. any third party API for this purpose ?

I am stuck in this API problem just like no bluetooth API in Window Phone 7. Need help .

Regards

Prozeck

Comment: what exactly do you want from a WiFi API? There are facilities to query the conenctino, but not set properties on it or change it.

Answer (score 1):

Bad news, there is no WiFi API for Windows Phone 7, either now, or in the 7.1 (Mango) update. Currently, your only means of communication is via HTTP.